# Lightning:Card- underline title

Tags: salesforce, lightning

I have a lightening card in my component.

```
 <lightning:card title="My Title">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="left" class="slds-m-ertical_medium">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3">
                <lightning:badge label=""/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="7">
                   ......
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
</lightning:card>
```

I've been looking for a way to underline the title "My Title".
But I haven't been able to find any.
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the lightning design system [documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/), it looks like that title is given the style class `slds-text-heading_small`, so you should be able to get the desired effect by adding this to your component's style section:

```
.THIS .slds-text-heading_small{
    text-decoration : underline ;
}
```